# Seekbar thumb doesn't show if it's a shape

Tags: android, drawable, shapes, seekbar

Seekbar:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
    android:paddingRight="20dip"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/bg"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
    android:thumbOffset="0px" />
```

Problem: Works if thumb drawable it's a bitmap, but with a shape like

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ffff0000" />
</shape>
```

The thumb doesn't show.

I tried with things like this:

```
Drawable thumb = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thumb);
thumb.setBounds(0,0,20,20);
seekBar.setThumb(thumb);
```

But still the same problem. The drawable is "there", it can be dragged, and it's in the correct place, but it's not visible. Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try add size to your shape this:

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ffff0000" />
<size
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Ahhh :) forgot about this. Thank you!